# Pytest: Is it possible to get error message from pytest_runtest_protocol

Tags: pytest

Using hook i.e., `conftest.py` we can capture `test case name` and its `status` but is it possible to capture `error message` using `pytest_runtest_protocol`

I found following snippet from pytest documentation:

```
def pytest_runtest_protocol(item, log=True, nextitem=None):
    # Provide's test case execution details
    reports = runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
    for report in reports:
        if report.when == 'call':
            print('\n%s --- %s' % (item.name, report.outcome))
    return True
```

In documentation it mentioned that `pytest_runtest_protocol` holds exception details as well

Answer (score 0):

Observed that we cannot get error message using `pytest_runtest_protocol()` after couple of search i have found answer:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    # execute all other hooks to obtain the report object
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()

    if rep.when == "call" and rep.failed:
        # Error message if failed
        print(rep.longreprtext)
```

[Reference](https://medium.com/hultner/pytest-save-full-error-output-to-file-ee37d6ccbd32)

Documented my changes [here](https://gist.github.com/adiralashiva8/fffdc9ad01362b8a1fa0e6f9b1b3e551) for others